# Ошибка при конвертации проекта на swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

Перевожу старый проект с swift 3 на swift 5, вылезли предуприждения, а непосредственно при запуске самой конвертации на swift 5 выдает еще и ошибки. Посмотрел подобные решения, но у меня не срабатывает. В build setting выставил по подобию(скрин ниже), в Project settings выбирал Legacy Build system, но ничего не помогло. А главное при запуске на симуляторе или девайсе ошибки уходят. В чем причина и какое решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо было сделать промежуточные конвертации Swift 3 -> Swift 4 -> Swift 4.2 -> Swift 5, так намного меньше проблем проявляется при конвертации и они более очевидные.

А судя по обрывкам ошибок "multiple commands produce..." необходимо проверить Build phases -> Copy Bundle Resources чтобы не было одинаковых файлов, как то README/ LICENSE.md и другие. Также просмотреть что в Compile Sources на предмет лишнего.

Answer (score 0):

Почисти DerivedData и сделай clean Project